# Cannot view additional sites in a wordpress multisite devlopment environment

Tags: php, wordpress, development-environment, multisite, wpmu

We are trying to setup a development environment for WordPress multi-site. Everything works fine in my localhost but while trying to set it up at the development environment. Only the main site can be created, edited and viewed but any new sites in the network are only created but can't be edited or viewed.
I attach few images and a snippet of wp-config.php.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE',true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'xx.x.xx0.9');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

[image: site-created]
[image: site-error]

Comment: Did you also make the changes to vhost or .htaccess file on your development environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you check /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to see if the root folder of your wordpress installation allow rewrite ? Something like :

< Directory /var/www/html/>
      AllowOverride All
< /Directory>

Comment: Thans and it worked :)